# Conversion from string "Syntax error in FROM clause." to type 'Boolean' is not valid. error in VB10

Tags: sql, vb.net, oop, ms-access

I'm making a register and login form using VB 10 and MS Access. My problem is when I register, in just the check username part (the part that checks if there will be a duplicate username), this error keeps on showing `Conversion from string "Syntax error in INSERT INTO stat" to type 'Boolean' is not valid.`. I am using class by the way and this is the function that I made for check username (user = table name, username = field name):

```
Public Class Class1
Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim comm As OleDb.OleDbCommand
Dim query As String

Function chkuser(ByVal username)
Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim reader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
Dim comm As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
Try
    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource=D:\db\activity.accdb"
    conn.Open()
    query = "select * from user where username='" & username & "'"
    comm = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, conn)
    reader = comm.ExecuteReader
    If reader.Read = True Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
    conn.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    Return ex.Message()
End Try
End Function
```

This is my codes in Form1 (TextBox1 = username, TextBox2 = password):

```
Public Class Class1
Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim comm As OleDb.OleDbCommand
Dim query As String 

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim db As New Class1
    If db.chkfields(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text) = True Then
        If db.chkuser(TextBox1.Text) = False Then
            If db.register(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text) = True Then
                MessageBox.Show("Registration successful")
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong")
            End If
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Username already taken")
        End If
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please complete all fields")
    End If
End Sub
```

Here is the register function:

```
Function register(ByVal username, ByVal password)
Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim reader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
Dim comm As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
Try
    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\db\activity.accdb"
    conn.Open()
    query = "insert into user (`username`,`password`) values('" & username & "','" & password & "')"
    comm = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, conn)
    reader = comm.ExecuteReader
    If reader.Read = True Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
    conn.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    Return ex.Message
End Try
End Function
```

Comment: You're testing the return value of chkuser as a Boolean, but when it errors, it will return a string. Turn on option explicit and option strict, fix the warnings that show, and give it another go.

Comment: When you don't declare your functions with the TYPE of what they return, be it string, boolean, integer, or whatever, then you invite all sorts of problems for yourself.  Let the IDE help you -- turn on Option String + Option Explicit, and it will show you places where things don't match.  Fix those -- this will take some time, but it's time well spent to make sure that you're getting a boolean where you expect a boolean, etc.

Comment: In your `register` function, your connection will never be closed.  You return from the function before the `conn.Close()` line is ever reached.  You should be getting a warning about unreachable code.  _Don't ignore warnings!_  Also, turn on Option Strict.  Your functions do not specify a return type.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure with the code, (i won't like to assume but if you can share it) but I think the problem is within the db.register function. It should be something like this.

```
public function register (byval username as string, byval password as string) as boolean

...
return bool

end function
```

Comment: Edited my post. Please check the register function. besides from username and password not set as string and not returning bool, what else should I do?

Comment: what is the reader for? try running your code. and see if it still has an error.